# Trying to convert the following php code to have a prepared statment

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and MySQL. I have the following code that works but now I need to incorporate prepared statements into. I have tried many things but with no luck.

The following is the original PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, address, city, phone, id FROM Lab7 WHERE name = '$name' ";
        mysql_select_db('muftih_Registration');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

This is my attempt that did not work:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, address, city, phone, id FROM Lab7 WHERE name = ?";
        $sql->bindParam('s', $name);
        mysql_select_db('muftih_Registration');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

I keep getting:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Comment: (1) `mysql_*` doesn't support prepared statements.  Use `mysqli_*` or PDO.  (2) `$sql` is a string.  You can't call a function on a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_` family does not support prepared statements, you'll need to migrate to `mysqli_` which is a different driver library. Furthermore, you **cannot** mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_` libraries together.

Lastly, `mysql_` has been deprecated for several years now, and has been removed in php 7.

Synopsis: **do not use mysql_**.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysqli on order to use prepared.

Let me show an example.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
 }

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, address, city, phone, id FROM Lab7 WHERE name = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $address, $city, $phone, $id);
    $stmt->fetch();

    echo "$name, $address, $city, $phone, $id"; // Print the retrieved row

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Or, better, use PDO.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps!